# Subfolder query string htaccess redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, query-string

Everything I can find for query string redirects talks about something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^view=home$
RewriteRule .? http://mywebsite.com/? [L,R=301]
```

That's great, but I'm dealing with a url that looks like this:

```
example.com/portfolio/?gal=16
```

If I test it without the "portfolio/" it will work fine, but my old site is indexed as above. Any tips on how I can make it work with my URL structure?

**EDIT** Current .htaccess contents

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# Canonical Remove www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirects

Redirect 301 /feedback http://example.com/testimonials
Redirect 301 /about http://example.com/about-us
Redirect 301 /contact http://example.com/contact-us

#futile attempts at query string redirects omitted
```

Thanks.

**New Edit to include @anubhava's suggestions**

Might as well give you the actual .htaccess content since the site is now live.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev.bayshorephotography.com$ [OR]
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://bayshorephotography.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Canonical Remove www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.bayshorephotography.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://bayshorephotography.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^gal=16$
RewriteRule .? http://bayshorephotography.com/portfolio/weddings-02/? [L,R=301]

Redirect 301 /feedback http://bayshorephotography.com/testimonials
Redirect 301 /about http://bayshorephotography.com/about-us
Redirect 301 /contact http://bayshorephotography.com/contact-us

#301 Redirect Entire Directory to remove /blog/ from all blog pages except the main archive itself
RedirectMatch 301 /blog(/.*)/ $1

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# Old Redirects that don't work
#Redirect 301 /portfolio?gal=20 http://bayshorephotography.com/portfolio-items/weddings-04/
#Redirect 301 /portfolio?gal=29 http://bayshorephotography.com/portfolio-items/our-world-03/
#Redirect 301 /portfolio?gal=16 http://bayshorephotography.com/portfolio-items/weddings-02/
#Redirect 301 /portfolio?gal=18 http://bayshorephotography.com/portfolio-items/weddings-04/
#Redirect 301 /portfolio?gal=28 http://bayshorephotography.com/portfolio-items/album-samples-01/
#Redirect 301 /portfolio?gal=19 http://bayshorephotography.com/portfolio-items/weddings-05/
#Redirect 301 /portfolio?gal=22 http://bayshorephotography.com/portfolio-items/portraits-01/
#Redirect 301 /portfolio?gal=24 http://bayshorephotography.com/portfolio-items/our-world-01/
#Redirect 301 /portfolio?gal=17 http://bayshorephotography.com/portfolio-items/weddings-03/
#Redirect 301 /portfolio?gal=36 http://bayshorephotography.com/portfolio-items/portraits-04/
#Redirect 301 /portfolio?gal=35 http://bayshorephotography.com/portfolio-items/portraits-03/
#Redirect 301 /portfolio?gal=32 http://bayshorephotography.com/portfolio-items/weddings-01/
#Redirect 301 /portfolio?gal=25 http://bayshorephotography.com/portfolio-items/our-world-02/
#Redirect 301 /portfolio?gal=23 http://bayshorephotography.com/portfolio-items/portraits-02/
#Redirect gone /portfolio?gal=34
#Redirect gone /portfolio?gal=33
#Redirect gone /portfolio?gal=27
#Redirect gone /portfolio?gal=21
```

Comment: Is there any .htaccess in `/portfolio/` directory?

Comment: It's not a directory. It's a permalink in WordPress. So, no.

Comment: Ah WP, can you post your current .htaccess in that case?

Comment: Edited post to include.  Thanks.

Comment: ok posted an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change order of your rules and keep 301/302 before WP rules:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Canonical Remove www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^view=home$
RewriteRule .? http://example.com/? [L,R=301]

# Redirects
RewriteRule ^feedback/?$ http://example.com/testimonials [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^about/?$ http://example.com/about-us [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^contact/?$ http://example.com/contact-us [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Darn. I have done exactly that and have the same result.  It's being ignored.  Here's what I added in the same order you did... RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^gal=16$
RewriteRule .? http://example.com/portfolio/weddings-02/? [L,R=301]

Comment: And `example.com/portfolio/?gal=16` didn't redirect? Even in new browser? Do you have some caching plugin enabled in WP?

Comment: Nothing happens. No caching enabled. Further, if I purposely make an error in the file it throws a server error.

Comment: What happens when you open: `example.com/port/?gal=16` (just for testing) Does URL change to `http://mywebsite.com/`?

Comment: I'm sorry - real website is omitted.  they should all read example.com - updating above now

Comment: Sure that's alright. Did you try to enter `http://example.com/port/?gal=16` and did the URL change to `http://example.com/`?

Comment: I did try that, and no, it did not.  The URL stays the same.

Comment: As per this simple rule it should have worked. Can you paste your latest .htaccess in your question again?

Comment: Seems to be working fine. I just tried `http://bayshorephotography.com/portfolio/?gal=16` and it got redirected to `http://bayshorephotography.com/portfolio/weddings-02/`

Comment: Yes! Sorry something must have been cached.  Thanks for your dedication to helping solve this.